# Create new column of vectors from two columns in R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this and am looking to create a new column that's a vector containing txStart and txEnd. I tried 
`subsetDF <- unite(subsetDF, interval, c(txStart, txEnd), sep = ", ", remove=FALSE)`
but this returns a character, and I want the output column to be a vector so later I can individually access the values for txStart and txEnd. I also tried 
`subsetDF['interval'] <- apply(subsetDF[,c('txStart', 'txEnd')], 2, func)`
but got this error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : argument "values" is missing, with no default`. Any help would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: So you want a column of vectors?

Comment: Yeah, a new column of 2-d vectors

Answer (score 4):

You should probably think through why you want to add a column with information you already have in two separate columns since this will only duplicate data and make accessing this data harder. Assuming you have a good reason, you can achieve what you want by making `interval` a list of vectors with the 2 values:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = letters[1:5],
  txStart = c(100, 200, 300, 400, 500),
  txEnd = c(120, 220, 320, 420, 520)
)

df$interval <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) c(df$txStart[i], df$txEnd[i]))
```

And then your data will look like this:

```
> df
  name txStart txEnd interval
1    a     100   120 100, 120
2    b     200   220 200, 220
3    c     300   320 300, 320
4    d     400   420 400, 420
5    e     500   520 500, 520
```

And if you want to e.g. access the `txEnd` of the 4th row you'd have to do this:

```
> df$interval[[4]][2]
[1] 420
```

Note that you have to use `[[` since you're first taking the subset of a list.